# Tensorflow for audio signal processing - detecting features intensity and delayes

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

For my studies I need to train a deep NN to identify certain sounds and their delays. We have 1X25K sample points (microphone output) and need quantification of events and their intensity.

In order to simplify the model to look more like the MNIST training procedure, for now we use the classification for the quantification (if there are two events each with intensity of 5 and 3, the output would be 8 and the delays vector).
we tried to throw the data [trainNum, 25000] to a 3 layered NN with 250, 100 and 50 neurons and adamoptimizer for three classes output as 100\ 010\001 [trainNum, 3]  . The cost is not reducing from 400 and accuracy is 30%.

Please would appreciate any help and comments.

additional information: 2700 samples, 270 batches, 10 epochs. Used the following tutorial and changed the data from the MNIST to out sound data - https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-neural-network-session-machine-learning-tutorial/

Thank you in advance

All the best,
AA